# Printing a Char after an Array of a Struct

Tags: c

When running my code so that it prints an `array` of `struct` followed by a `char`, it will not print the `char` unless I place it in a separate `printf` statement. I'm wondering *why*?

The practice problem prompt:

- A complex number is a number of the form a + ib, where a is called
  the real part, b is called the imaginary part, and i =  .  In this
  problem, you do NOT calculate a complex number; rather you will just
  read in the real and imaginary parts and print them.  •

  - Write a
    program that defines a type for a structure for a complex number (it
    should have two members, for the real and imaginary parts).
  - Prompt
    the user separately to enter values for the real and imaginary parts,
    and store them in a structure variable of this type.
  - Print the
    complex number in the form a + ib.  (Just print the value of a, then
    the string   “+ i”, and then the value of b).
  - **Modify your program to
    have an array of structures for complex numbers.**

When I code the solution it the `printf` statement in this format, it works:

`printf("a + bi = %d + %d",mynum[0],mynum[1]);
 printf("%c\n",imaginary);`

Whereas code in this format omits the `char` and therefor doesn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    int a, // real part
        b; // imaginary part
}ComplexNum;

void main()
{
    int a, //real part
        b; //imaginary part
    char imaginary = 'i'; //imaginary number

    printf("Enter the real part: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Enter the imaginary part: ");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    ComplexNum mynum[2] = {a,b};
    printf("a + bi = %d + %d%c\n",mynum[0],mynum[1],imaginary);

    return 0;
}
```

e.g., if I enter 2 and 3 for the input, the output yields "a + bi = 2 + 3" rather than "a + bi = 2 + 3i".

I realize there are work arounds, e.g., by instead coding it as `printf("a + bi = %d + %di\n",mynum[0],mynum[1]);` so that the i is included in the `printf` statement rather than included in a variable, but again, I want to know *why* this error is occurring.

Thanks!

Comment: `ComplexNum mynum[2] = {a,b};`? Did you mean `ComplexNum mynum = {a, b};` instead? You'd also have to modify `mynum[0]` and `mynum[1]` accordingly.

Comment: Even with `ComplexNum mynum = {a, b};`, you still need `printf("a + bi = %d + %d%c\n",mynum.a, mynum.b, imaginary);`.

Comment: If you turn on warnings you should see all kinds of problems.

Comment: You clearly missing the real problem here. Printing a char next to an integer is not an issue.

Comment: Oops! You're right, @frslm. Thank you—I don't have the hang of this language quite yet. Still, I wonder why `printf("a + bi = %d + %d %c\n",mynum[0],mynum[1],imaginary);` did not print for `char imaginary = 'i'`?

Comment: @Octavius It does print the `i`. The problem is here `......\n",mynum[0],mynum[1],im.....` They need to be `mynum.a` and `mynum.b`

Comment: @Octavius, `printf()` expects an int for `%d`, but you've passed in `mynum[0]` and `mynum[1]` (which are a different type) so you end up with undefined behaviour; anything could happen.

Comment: @frslm Ah, I think I'm starting to understand. So, because `%d` was expected but I fed it something else, it's still anticipating `%d` and thus giving me some other result instead? I was thrown by it still "spitting back" the value I fed into the input for both `%d`, and thought that it would accept another `type` nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Printing a `char` next to an `int` is not a problem.

1) You 're creating an array of `ComplexNum` when you only need one. You need to change:

```
ComplexNum mynum[2] = {a,b};
```

to:

```
ComplexNum mynum = {a,b};
```

or:

```
ComplexNum mynum;
mynum.a = a;
mynum.b = b;
```

2) You have `%d` and then you 're passing a `ComplexNum`. You need to change:

```
printf("a + bi = %d + %d%c\n",mynum[0],mynum[1],imaginary);
```

to:

```
printf("a + bi = %d + %d%c\n",mynum.a,mynum.b,imaginary);
```